# add go button MapKit Swift

Tags: swift

I am using MapKit. It draws the route between the two entered locations. But the go button does not appear. So he draws the route but doesn't describe how to go on the route. You can see in the photo. It puts the pins, but the Go to route button does not appear. How can I activate the go button?

[image: route photo]

```
class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(pinTitle:String, pinSubTitle:String, location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = pinTitle
        self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
        self.coordinate = location
    }
}

class mapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:39.173209 , longitude: -94.593933)
        let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:38.643172 , longitude: -90.177429)

        let sourcePin = customPin(pinTitle: "Kansas City", pinSubTitle: "aa", location: sourceLocation)
        let destinationPin = customPin(pinTitle: "St. Louis", pinSubTitle: "ddd", location: destinationLocation)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(sourcePin)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(destinationPin)

        let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation)
        let destinationPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation)

        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlaceMark)
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let directionResonse = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("we have error getting directions==\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }

            let route = directionResonse.routes[0]
            self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
        }
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0
        return renderer
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```